# Is there any way to treat multicollinearity between two variables in dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-science

I am doing regression problem where I have to predict weekly sales of 45 outlet of a departmental store. I have a variable named temperature(values in Celsius) and I want to do feature engineering on this column as a practice so I came with the the idea of creating another column which will also be a temperature column but values will be in farenhite which will be derived from celsius column, but that will lead to multicollinearity between these two variable, Is there any way to treat multicollinearity between two variable or should I go with another approach?

Comment: read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, add more details

Comment: The two columns would both measure the same temperature data with different units. My thought is that there should only be one column to measure the effect of temperature. For example, if you were using distance there would be no reason to have different columns representing the *same distance* in units of feet, meters, miles, kilometers, and light-years - you would only use one of those measures of distance.